# Write rows to CSV from SQL Server Trigger

Tags: sql

We need to write a trigger so that when rows inserted into a sql server table meeting certain conditions, they are then written to a windows OS flat file in CSV format.

Are there any commands short of running a xp_cmdshell that would allow us to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a SQL CLR trigger to do this. PS, I wouldn't!